# Android - App downloaded from Google Play Store not behaving as it is working during development

Tags: android, notifications, google-play, android-workmanager

I have developed an android prayer alarms application which using Worker Manager for firing of local notifications.

It is working fine on development mode, also tested the release build on device and it is working fine. But when app is uploaded to Google Play Store and downloaded from the store, it is not behaving correctly. The local notifications are not firing as they were suppose to fire.
This behaviour is fine during local installation but after downloading from store, it does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

is your app connected with any online services? after uploading app to play store, play console signs the app with an unique sign key which is different from your debug and release sign keys. uploading app to the play store shouldn't be a problem with worker.

check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

also if you are using minify/proguard then be sure to check the pro-guard rules and code references.

Comment: No, app is not connected to any server nor does relies on any external api. It calculates notifications timings for a day based on user's location and registers WorkManager, which in results fires local notifications.
I understand about signing and and stuff. I already have signed (release) build installed on device and tested thoroughly, but after uploading that same build to Play Store and downloading that from there, is does not work properly, i.e. does not fire local notifications.